# MAUI: button not working in custom element (in derived class) after overriding "ArrangeOverride"

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to create a custom control in Maui from several buttons.

```
public class Page1 : StackLayout
{  
    int i, n=0;
    byte[] wdt = new byte[255];  
    public void Add(string t)  
    {  
        Button bt = new Button {  
            Text = t, 
            BorderWidth = 1,
            BorderColor = Colors.Black,
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
            TextColor = Colors.Black,
            Padding = new Thickness(2, 0),
            HeightRequest = 30,
            IsEnabled = true,        
        };  
        bt.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;  
        Children.Add(bt);  
        n++;  
    }

    protected override Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Size MeasureOverride(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        var size = base.MeasureOverride(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
        var mySize = new Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Size();
        i = 0;
        foreach (var c in this.Children)
        {
            wdt[i] = (byte)(c.DesiredSize.Width);
            i++;
        }
        return mySize;
    }

    protected override Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Size ArrangeOverride(Rect bounds)
    {
        var lct = new Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Point();
        Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Size finalSize = new();
        int x = 0, y = 10;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            lct.X = x;
            lct.Y = y;
            var c = Children[i];
            c.Arrange(new Rect(lct, c.DesiredSize));
            x += wdt[i] + 50;
            y += 40;
        }
        return finalSize;
    }  

    private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
    {
        Button bt = (Button)sender;  
        if(bt.BackgroundColor== Colors.LightPink)bt.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        else bt.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightPink;
    }
}
```

Code-behind of MainPage:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage  
{  
    public MainPage()  
    {   
        InitializeComponent();  
        Chld.Add("Button1");  
        Chld.Add("Button2");  
        Chld.Add("Button3");  
    }   
}
```

XAML of MainPage:

```xml
<ContentPage 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiButton"  
             x:Class="MauiButton.MainPage">  
      <local:Page1 x:Name="Chld"></local:Page1>  
</ContentPage>
```

Runs on a Windows Machine. On a phone (Android) without ArrangeOverride too. But if I override ArrangeOverride the buttons will be visible but the Clicked(OnButtonClicked) event will not fire. When the button is pressed, nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Comment: I tried on Android and that's worked

Comment: Quentin Guillaume  I'm sorry, after overriding ArrangeOverride, the Clicked (On Button Clicked) event will not fire.

Comment: What's the variable `wdt` and `i`? Could you please post the full code of class `Page1`?

Comment: @Quentin Guillaume
 After overriding ArrangeOverride, the Clicked(OnButtonClicked) event does not work.

Comment: @Jessie Zhang -MSFT
  i- counter; wdt[i] - width of i  button
The full code of the class Page1 is given at the beginning

Comment: I did a test based on your code, and it works fine on Windows, but not on Android. So you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) . Thanks for your support and feedback.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT maybe you could create an issue?  Sorry to be glib but it would be nice if MSFT took responsibility for their mobile frameworks for a change.